# Type reduce array return objects bu id

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, keyof

Usually when we are fetching we get an array with complex objects with ids. Like this:

```
const arrayOfObjects = [
  {
    id: '56gfl3Y23',
    brand: 'Bosch',
    price: 1234,
    specs: ['feature1', 'feature2', 'reature3'],
    // ... other fields
  },
  // ... other objects
]
```

In Javascript we may simply use reduce method to create an array of objects with id as a key.

```
const productsById = arrayOfObjects.reduce((acc, product) => {
  acc[product.id] = product;
  return acc;
}, []);
```

There`s no problem to describe interface of a product like

```
interface IProduct {
  id: string,
  brand: string,
  price: number,
  specs: string[],
  // ...
}
```

But when I try to describe this reduce function I absolutely get stucked. I suppose I need to use a generic, but this did not help as it throws an error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.` How can I resolve it without using `any`?

Answer (score 1):

`[]` creates an *array* - if your indicies aren't in ascending numeric order, use a plan object instead, with `{}`. One option is to use generics to indicate that that accumulator object is of type `Record<string, IProduct>`.

```
const productsById = arrayOfObjects.reduce<Record<string, IProduct>>((acc, product) => {
  acc[product.id] = product;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

A quicker way is to use `Object.fromEntries`.

```
const productsById = Object.fromEntries(
  arrayOfObjects.map(obj => [obj.id, obj])
);
```

Comment: Yes, I`ve missed that I should use an object instead of an array. And it seems like the problem was in more complex interface that I used (tuples and literal types in it). Simplifying the interface and using your first solution solves the problem. But the second solution works even with more complex interface. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

From what you're trying to assign, you should start with an object. The type can either be a Record or a typed object.

```
const productsById = arrayOfObjects.reduce((acc, product) => {
  acc[product.id] = product;
  return acc;
}, {} as Record<string,IProduct>); // or {[id: string]: IProduct}
```

as an extra, you can use lodash to key by a property.

```
const productsById = _.keyBy(arrayOfObjects, 'id')
```